# Python Virtual Environments duplicate files

Tags: python, virtual, virtual-environment

I install package X in my virtual environment which is already installed in my (base) environment (same version). Does that mean that my drive will have the same files 2 times?

This is a storage issue basically, I want to make sure I do not have the same files again again taking space in my computer.

Comment: you can easily check by activating venv, running `pip install` and checking if the size of your venv folder changed.

Comment: So all of the files I installed will be visible in the folder at which I created the virtual environment? Also would you recommend creating environments with venv rather than conda?

Comment: Yep, in general everything you install in venv should appear in the folder for the venv. I'm probably not the best person to provide an opinion on venv vs conda as I have no idea what conda is, but I use a Mac for work so I generally just stick with a venv. I also have a shortcut setup in my ~/.bashrc so it automatically activates venvs when I `cd` into a folder which has a venv directory.